# Sencha Architect gened code Tab Panel & List - List does not show in Tab...?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Am I missing something? Generated code below image.

List works fine independantly of the tab... can you not put a list inside a tab container or is there an option i additionally need? Thanks Greg

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'info',
                html: 'Welcome',
                itemId: 'home'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'About',
                iconCls: 'info',
                html: 'Awsome',
                itemId: 'about'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                title: 'Stylists',
                iconCls: 'info',
                html: '',
                itemId: 'contact',
                scrollable: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'list',
                        docked: 'top',
                        styleHtmlContent: true,
                        itemTpl: [
                            '<div>{fname} {lname} {title}</div>'
                        ],
                        store: 'LSstylistStore'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'bottom'
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to Add Layout: Type: Fit, which made the list display inside the tab container.  In Architect select the tab containing the list and in Ext.Container layout option select "fit"

```
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Stylists',
            iconCls: 'info',
            html: '',
            itemId: 'Stylists',
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },
            scrollable: true,
```